# How can I convert mixed string list to int and float (put each element to a list according to it nature)?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Here's a simple example:

```
def separateFloatInt(L):
    l1=list()
    l2=list()
    for x in L:
        if type(x)==int:
            l1.append(x)
        else:
            l2.append(x)
    return l1,l2
            
L=['2', '3.5', '6', '5.1', '9.8', '7.8', '5', '3.3', '0.5', '9']    
integer,reel=separateFloatInt(L)
```

How can I separate one list into two list, one has only integers, the other has only floats?

Comment: Your list contains only _strings_. If you want to know how to convert those to numbers, so your code _can_ partition them into two other lists, look _that_ up.

Comment: I convert them to which type? float or int ?? @jonrsharpe, then ?

Comment: If you converted them all to the same type, how would you then partition them?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def separateFloatInt(L):
    l1, l2 = [], []
    for v in L:
        try:
            l1.append(int(v))
        except ValueError:
            l2.append(float(v))
    return l1, l2


L = ["2", "3.5", "6", "5.1", "9.8", "7.8", "5", "3.3", "0.5", "9"]
integer, reel = separateFloatInt(L)

print(integer)
print(reel)
```

Prints:

```py
[2, 6, 5, 9]
[3.5, 5.1, 9.8, 7.8, 3.3, 0.5]
```

Comment: Perfect !!!! thank you so much.
I am trying to use split, to separate integer part from float part, then test the float if it is 0 , it is anteger value, if it is different to 0 it is float, but error appearing : need more than 1 value to unpack

, can you help to realise this idea ?
        a,b=x.split(".")
@Andrej Kesely

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help

I developped this solution as well.

```
def separateFloatInt(L):
    L=[float(x) for x in L]
    L=[str(x) for x in L]
    l1=list()
    l2=list()
    for x in L:
       print(x)
       a,b=x.split(".")
       if int(b)!=0:
           l1.append(x) # float
       else:
           l2.append(a) # int
    return l1,l2      
            
p=read()
print(p)
real,integer=separateFloatInt(p)
```

Output for:

```
L=['2', '3.2', '6', '3.5', '8.4', '8.8', '9', '5', '4.1', '5']
```

Is

```
print(real)
print(integer)
['3.2', '3.5', '8.4', '8.8', '4.1']
['2', '6', '9', '5', '5']
```